# trouble with 'breaks' in for loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop

I'm writing language for an analytics programming course where I'm asked to check for duplicate elements in a vector. While I am able to code the logic, I'm trying to use 'breaks' in the code so that once I find a duplicate it doesn't run through the rest of the elements. In my code, I'm able to break out of the 'while loop', but not the 'for loop'. I Could use advice on how to add a second break so that the counter stops at 3 in the below, and doesn't jump back into the for loop.

```
x <- c(3, -7, 6, 3, 1, -7)
n <- length(x); n # = 6
counter <- 0
answer <- FALSE
for (i in 1:(n-1)) {
    v <- i + 1
    while (v <= n) {
      counter <- counter + 1
      if (x[i] == x[v]) {
        answer <- TRUE
        break
      }
      else {
        v <- v + 1
      }
    }
}
answer # = TRUE
counter # = 13, SHOULD BE 3
```

I expect to stop at 3 loops, but the breaks I've added after the brackets have not worked, so I have only successfully added the break in the while loop, but it is still going through the remaining elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `answer` cannot be true if `while` loop is not broken, put the `answer` value check after `while` loop and break `for` loop if `answer` is true:

```
x <- c(3, -7, 6, 3, 1, -7)
n <- length(x); n # = 6
counter <- 0
answer <- FALSE
for (i in 1:(n-1)) {
    v <- i + 1
    while (v <= n) {
      counter <- counter + 1
      if (x[i] == x[v]) {
        answer <- TRUE
        break
      }
      else {
        v <- v + 1
      }

    } #end while

    if(answer == TRUE)         
       break

} #end for
answer # = TRUE
counter # = 13, SHOULD BE 3
```